# Runtime of the recursive algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I am learning algorithm complexities. So far it has been an interesting ride. There is so much going behind the scenes that I need to understand. I find it difficult to understand complexity in recursive function.

my_func takes an array parameter 'A' of length n. Runtime of some_func() is constant.

```
def my_func(A): 
   if (n < 4):
     some_func(); /* O(1) time */
   else:
     [G1, G2, G3, G4] = split(A) /* split A into 4 disjoint subarrays of size n/4 each */
     my_func([G1, G3]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
     my_func([G1, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
     my_func([G2, G3]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
     my_func([G2, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2 */
     some_other_func(); /* split() and some_other_func() take O(n) time */
```

**Questions**

1. Can I say the asymptotic runtime of my_func is:

> T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n), T(1) = O(1)

because my_func is called recursively 4 times for (n/2) size, then split is O(n). The base case keeps T(1) = O(1)

2. What is the total number of steps performed by my_func(A)?

I know that if there are nested for loops then simply multiply. How to calculate in this case? I was trying use Google search and it point to Omega(n^3). Is that correct?

Now what if I rewrite this function as:

```
def new_func(A): /* A is array of length n 8/
   if (n < 4):
     some_func(); /* O(1) time */
   else:
     [G1, G2, G3, G4] = split(A) /* split A into 4 disjoint subarrays of size n/4 each 
     new_func([G1, G2])
     new_func([G2, G3])
     new_func([G3, G4]); /* recurses on size n/2  */
     some_other_func(); /* split() and some_other_func() take O(n) time */
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the number of steps now?

   I am thinking it will be omega(n^3)
2. Is new_func faster than nlog(n)?